# Php mysql results as array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table like this:

Table: **categories**

**id** | **name**

1 | Foo

2 | Bar

**PHP**

In php I want to print out like $category[1] (the name of the choosen id)

So if I write:

`echo $category[1];`

The result will be "Foo"

Sadly I've only come this far...

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

Comment: ever heard of [this](http://www.google.com)? You got the row data in `$row`, `while` cycle goes through all rows, where is the problem? just store the data from `$row` into some array

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work that way. The `$row`'s index `[1]` would refer to the column value (depending on the column order passed in SELECT) of each row and not to the actual value itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['name'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Result:

```
1 Foo
2 Bar
```

Comment: Yup, also, keep in mind that mysql_* is deprecated, so please use mysqli_* or PDO in order to avoid mysql injections!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");
?>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note: `mysql_*` is deprecated. Use `mysqli_`

Answer (score 0):

This actually solved it!

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");
$data = array();
$x = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[$x] = $row['nam'];
    $x++;
}
echo $data[2];`

Answer (score 0):

With old style mysql which does not have iterators for result-sets, you can create your own easily, for example in PHP 5.5 with a generator:

```
$rows = function($result)  {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        yield $row;
};
```

An Iterator then can be converted into an array (if the Iterator alone is not sufficient yet):

```
$array = iterator_to_array($rows($result));
```

If you're below PHP 5.5, you can make use of [`FetchingIterator`](https://github.com/hakre/Iterator-Garden/blob/master/src/FetchingIterator.php) which works similarly.